# Automate Microsoft SQL Script and send the Result to email

Tags: mysql, database-mail, scheduled-tasks

My organization asked me to setup monitoring for below query and the query  needs to run every hour(Automated) , if the below query status results other than STARTED or COMPLETED send them as failure and I'm new to SQL please can some help me with this to tune the query and with email requirement?

**SQL query**

```
 SELECT 
    i.JOB_NAME, e.STATUS
FROM
    BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION e
        JOIN
    BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE i ON i.JOB_INSTANCE_ID = e.JOB_INSTANCE_ID
WHERE
    i.JOB_NAME IN ('STORE_DOCS')
```

[image]

Comment: please  read https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions and add the missing information

Comment: **Microsoft** MySQL?